# VM Cloning Transfers cause Blade outage

Tags: performance, cloning, vmware-server

I used to be able to do this sort of thing without any problems, though the speed was still not all that great.

Hardware:
HP Proliant C3000 enclosure
BL460c G7 blades
BLc SB40c Storage blade
Enclosure is connected to Netgear Gigabit switch

Nowadays, whenever I try to do a Clone in Vcenter from one blade to another, one of the blades loses connectivity to Vcenter and the network - usually not the one involved in the transfer.  It appears to me that the blade loses network connectivity altogether, but the VMs conitnue to run.  I can't confirm this because I can't ping any of them during this time.  But the blade power remains constant and when the transfer finishes, the blade reconnects and all services are restored.

Knowing this problem was occurring and that I had to a massive VM transfer that could take overnight, I powered down all VMs with the hopes that the transfer speed would improve.  This, sadly, was not the case. The transfer took longer than expected and I had to cancel it altogether just to get services back up for business.

So my two concerns are
1. Why such slow transfer speeds when all blades are communicating via the interconnects or, at worst, a Gigabit switch?
2. Does anyone know the cause of the blade losing connectivity during transfer processes of any kind?

These are intolerant symptoms when one has VM's that require more space than what is simply required for an OS.
I realize this may not be due to VM configuration, but it quite possibly could be...

Comment: Try asking over at [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), this is not a programming question.

Comment: Gotcha.  thanks, I'll do that